# Consumer assignment with multiple topics with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Apologies if this has been already covered before here, I couldn't find anything closely related. I have this Kafka Streams app which reads from multiple topics, persist the records on a DB and then publish an event to an output topic. Pretty straightforward, it's stateless in terms of kafka local stores. (Topology below)

Topic1(T1) has 5 partitions, Topic2(T2) has a single partition. The issue here is, while consuming from two topics, if I want to go "full speed" with T1 (5 consumers), it doesn't guarantee that I will have dedicated consumers for each partition on T1. It will be distributed within the two topic partitions and I might end up with unbalanced consumers (and idle consumers), something like below:

- [c1: t1p1, t1p3], [c2: t1p2, t1p5], [c3: t1p4, t2p1], [c4: (idle consumer)], [c5: (idle consumer)]
- [c1: t1p1, t1p2], [c2: t1p5], [c3: t1p4, t2p1], [c4: (idle consumer)], [c5: t1p3]

With that said:

1. Is it a good practice having a topology that reads from multiple topics within the same KafkaStreams instance?
2. Is there any way to achieve a partition assignment like the following if I want go "full speed" for T1? [c1: t1p1, t2p1], [c2: t1p2], [c3: t1p3], [c4: t1p4], [c5: t1p5]
3. Which of the topologies below is most optimal to what I want to achieve? Or is it completely unrelated?

Option A (Current topology)

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: topic1-source (topics: [TOPIC1])
      --> topic1-processor
    Processor: topic1-processor (stores: [])
      --> topic1-sink
      <-- topic1-source
    Sink: topic1-sink (topic: OUTPUT-TOPIC)
      <-- topic1-processor

  Sub-topology: 1
    Source: topic2-source (topics: [TOPIC2])
      --> topic2-processor
    Processor: topic2-processor (stores: [])
      --> topic2-sink
      <-- topic2-source
    Sink: topic2-sink (topic: OUTPUT-TOPIC)
      <-- topic2-processor
```

Option B:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: topic1-source (topics: [TOPIC1])
      --> topic1-processor
    Source: topic2-source (topics: [TOPIC2])
      --> topic2-processor
    Processor: topic1-processor (stores: [])
      --> response-sink
      <-- topic1-source
    Processor: topic2-processor (stores: [])
      --> response-sink
      <-- topic2-source
    Sink: response-sink (topic: OUTPUT-TOPIC)
      <-- topic2-processor, topic1-processor
```

3. If I use two streams for each topic instead of a single streams with multiple topic, would that work for what I am trying to achieve?

```
config1.put("application.id", "app1");
KakfaStreams stream1 = new KafkaStreams(config1, topologyTopic1);
stream1.start();

config2.put("application.id", "app2");
KakfaStreams stream2 = new KafkaStreams(config2, topologyTopic2);
stream2.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial assignments you describe, would never happen with Kafka Streams (And also not with any default Consumer config). If there are 5 partitions and you have 5 consumers, each consumer would get 1 partition assigned (for a plain consumer with a custom `PartitionAssignor` you could do the assignment differently, but all default implementations would ensure proper load balancing).

> Is it a good practice having a topology that reads from multiple topics within the same KafkaStreams instance?

There is not issue with that.

> Is there any way to achieve a partition assignment like the following if I want go "full speed" for T1? [c1: t1p1, t2p1], [c2: t1p2], [c3: t1p3], [c4: t1p4], [c5: t1p5]

Depending how you write your topology, this would be the assignment Kafka Streams uses out-of-the-box. For you two options, option B would result in this assignment.

> Which of the topologies below is most optimal to what I want to achieve? Or is it completely unrelated?

As mentioned above, Option B would result in the assignment above. For Option A, you could actually even use a 6th instance and each instance would processes exactly one partition (because there are two sub-topologies, you get 6 tasks, 5 for sub-topology-0 and 1 for sub-topology-1; sub-topologies are scaled out independently of each other); for Option A, you only get 5 tasks though because there is only one sub-topology and thus the maximum number of partitions of both input topic (that is 5) determines the number of tasks.

> If I use two streams for each topic instead of a single streams with multiple topic, would that work for what I am trying to achieve?

Yes, it would be basically the same as Option A -- however, you get two consumer groups and thus "two application" instead of one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthias! Some considerations: 

1. I did some testing by scaling the T1 partition count up to 15 and T2, up to 5. Also, I ensured T1 had events on its 15 partitions, and for T2, only for one partition. I ended up with 5 active consumers and 10 idle consumers (containers). What am I missing here?

Comment: 2. As you mentioned, two streams worked big time, I ended up with the assignment I want. Will give a try changing the topology to Option B. Again, thanks again for your time! :)

Comment: Not sure. For Option A should get 20 tasks (you should be able to confirm from the log4j output) and those should get distributed over all consumers. What do you exactly mean by "idle"? No task/partitions assigned?

Comment: I stand corrected: Ended up with 4 active consumers. Here's how I ended up with: c1=[0_3, 1_0] / c2=[0_10, 0_13, 0_14, 0_4, 0_6] / c3=[0_1, 0_2, 0_5, 0_8] / c4=[0_0, 0_11, 0_12, 0_7, 0_9]. The way I see (and based on what you described above -- Keep me honest), this happens because I am using the Option A as topology (described above). If I switch it to Option B, I would end up with a 1:1 assignment + for T1.

Comment: So the task seems to be correct. You have `1_0` for the single partitioned topic for sub-topology 1 and 15 tasks for sub-topolgy 0 (the naming is `<subTopology>_<partition>`). -- if you would go with Option B, there would be 15 tasks, with task `0_0` processing partition 0 of both input topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthias! This was really helpful!